# ng-repeat not working until after submit button is hit twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am messing with the google maps API and using angular, and I am having an issue binding the data from the API to a variable and displaying it correctly with an ng-repeat. The ng-repeat is supposed to list the name property of the place objects, but it does not do that unless I enter the same zipcode twice. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "openApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Open Sesame</title>
    <script src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?     key=AIzaSyArO1n-5w8xxPblR_aDxV6Ul1VLik3_pRY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src = "vendors/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src = "assets/scripts/composite.all.min.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "assets/styles/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller = "MainController as main">
    <h1>Is it open?</h1>

    <!-- <button ng-click = ""></button> -->
    <div id = "googleMap"></div>
    <form>
      <input type = "text" ng-model = "main.zipcode"/>
      <input type = "submit" ng-click = "main.enterZip()" />
    </form>

    <div id = "displayInfo">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "item in main.openPlaces">
          test {{item.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the client side javascript:

```
angular.module('openApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$http', function($http){
    var vm = this;
    vm.latitude;
    vm.longitude;

    vm.openPlaces = [];
    initialize();
    vm.enterZip = function(){
      $http.get('/zipcodeApi/'+ vm.zipcode)
        .then(function(response){
          vm.latitude = response.data.lat;
          vm.longitude = response.data.lng;
          initialize();
        })
    }


      function initialize(){
          var mapLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(vm.latitude,     vm.longitude);

          var openNow = [];

          var mapProp = {
            center: mapLocation,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

          var placesRequest = {
            location: mapLocation,
            radius: '2000',
            types: ['restaurant'],
            keyword: 'restaurant',

          };

          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

          service.nearbySearch(placesRequest, function(results, status)  {
            if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var listedHours = results[i].opening_hours;
                if(typeof listedHours != 'undefined' &&  listedHours.open_now === true){
                  openNow.push(results[i]);
                  var place = results[i];
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                  });
                }
              }
            }
            vm.openPlaces = openNow;
          })//closes nearbySearch()

      }
  }]);
```

Comment: hmmm...I've replicated most of your code and mocked up what the google map service is doing and I don't see anything wrong code wise. Best thing to do would be to open browser dev tools, put a break point both in the enterZip().then() success function and the service.nearbySearch() function to see if the openNow array is being filled the first time.

Answer (score 0):

MainController would work because you named your controller MainController in the JS file. And that's the same reason MainController as main won't work.